# Angular Module Federation: Not loading MFE from remote port

Tags: angular, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

I am working on angular module fedration for micro-frontend, most of the setup is done both Shell and MFE is parally working fine, But when I try to use the path for MFE I am getting below error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG05100: Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the `CommonModule` instead.
Error: NG05100: Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the `CommonModule` instead.
```

Not sure what is gone wrong.
My MFE webpack config file:

```
const {
  shareAll,
  withModuleFederationPlugin,
} = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");

module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({
  name: "identity",

  exposes: {
    "./Module": "./projects/identity/src/app/app.module.ts",
  },

  shared: {
    ...shareAll({
      singleton: true,
      strictVersion: true,
      requiredVersion: "auto",
    }),
  },
});
```

My webpack config for Shell:

```
const {
  shareAll,
  withModuleFederationPlugin,
} = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");

module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({
  remotes: {
    identity: "http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.js",
  },

  shared: {
    ...shareAll({
      singleton: true,
      strictVersion: true,
      requiredVersion: "auto",
    }),
  },
});
```

Everything was auto generated because I used the CLI, Here's the route in Shell App:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'identity',
    loadChildren: () => import('identity/Module').then((m) => m.AppModule),
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering error message, the problem is that both, Shell and MFE exported module, are having `BrowserModule` in imports, but application must have just one of them.

So if you want applications being able to run as separate apps and as microfrontend app together: in MFE you should separate your code to 2 modules:

- some `my-export.module.ts` - for exporting it in MFE webpack config:

```
@NgModule({imports:[CommonModule], exports:[RouterModule], ...})
export class MyExportModule
{
  ...
}
```

```
  exposes: {
    "./MyExportModule": "./projects/identity/src/app/my-export/my-export.module.ts"
  }
```

- root `app.module.ts` - just empty wrapper for running MFE as separate application with routing to MyExportModule

```
var routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  loadChildren: () => import('./my-export/my-export.module.ts').then(m => m.MyExportModule)
}]

@NgModule({imports:[RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],...})
export class AppModule {}
```

Shell application will remain without changes.

So, as a result, Shell will import BrowserModule, and exported module - CommonModule.